# javascript addClass not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Goal:** To change an input field's border color to red when the input is NOT a valid/correct input. ex. If in the password field, the input is "abcd" the border color should be red because "abcd" is not between 8-20 characters.

**The** **Problem:** When a css class is added (via javascript) to an html input, the result is that that line and any following lines of javascript never run.

```
<style type="text/css">
.redborder { border:1px solid red; }
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#email').keyup(function() {
        checkInput("email");
    });
});

function checkInput(id) {
    alert("Got here");
    var field = document.getElementById("email");
    if (field.value == null || field.value === "") {
        alert("Adding 'redborder' class");
        field.addClass('redborder');
        alert("Added 'redborder' class");
    } else {
        alert("Removing 'redborder' class");
        field.removeClass('redborder');
        alert("Removed 'redborder' class");
    }
}
</script>
```

In this code, when I typing into the email field, the "Got Here" and "Removing 'redborder' class" alerts show up. The "Removed 'red border' class" alert and red border never show up however.

Comment: `addClass` is not a native JS method, if you want to use native JS it has a property called `classList` which has a method called `add`, so it should be `field.classList.add('redborder')`.

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820). You should have seen an error like "Undefined is not a function".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery selector on field. Change:

```
var field = document.getElementById("email");
```

to:

```
var field = $('#email');
```

`.addClass()` is a jQuery method, not a native JavaScript method. By using the jQuery selector, you automatically have access to all methods attached to jQuery's prototype object.

Remember that the jQuery object is a superset of the native DOM object. That is, the jQuery object has all native DOM properties and methods, plus those added by jQuery and any jQuery extensions that you have on your page.

Comment: a n explanation of why this is the answer would be good: like - you cannot use jQuery (addClass) on a normally selected (not with jQuery) element, you have to wrap it in jQuery beforehand.

Comment: @DrCord Yep. Sorry about that. I realized it was a little vague after I posted it and decided to edit it for clarification. It should be better now. Thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Will be accepting in 9mins when I'm allowed.

Comment: @War10ck - yeah, now instead of only an answer to the OPs question, it is a resource for future people to actually figure out why that is happening, I love SO! (mostly) :D

Comment: Worked - thanks. Being a new user of JQuery I was not aware that the former reference will execute the function only after JQuery has finished.

Answer (score 7):

You are accessing element by DOM object, to access the jQuery method you need to call using jquery object.

```
$(field).addClass('redborder');
```

Comment: I want to clarify that this answer was integral to the question I asked since setting my whole field to $('#email'); causes the field.value to not behave the same way as it previously was behaving. In the end, this was the change I went for because it is a single-line change rather than changing my entire variable to a jQuery selector. Thanks @Rashmin Javiya!